# Modules in VSC and terminal are not shared

Tags: python

recently i had to download some modules for a script I'm working on, I tried to download the module using pip in the MacOS terminal as i always do. But for some reason when i moved back to VSC i just got ModuleNotFoundError. Then i checked with pip list in the VSC terminal and sure enough the module had ont been downloaded, but it was when i did the exact same check on the terminal.

--- VISUAL STUDIO CODE TERMINAL----

pip list
Package                Version

---

brotlipy               0.7.0
certifi                2021.10.8
cffi                   1.15.0
charset-normalizer     2.0.12
colorama               0.4.4
conda                  4.12.0
conda-package-handling 1.8.0
cryptography           36.0.2
cycler                 0.11.0
emoji                  2.0.0
et-xmlfile             1.1.0
fonttools              4.33.2
idna                   3.3
kiwisolver             1.4.2
matplotlib             3.5.1
numpy                  1.22.3
openpyxl               3.0.10
packaging              21.3
pandas                 1.4.3
Pillow                 9.1.0
pip                    22.0.4
pycosat                0.6.3
pycparser              2.21
pyOpenSSL              22.0.0
pyparsing              3.0.8
PySocks                1.7.1
python-dateutil        2.8.2
pytz                   2022.2.1
requests               2.27.1
ruamel-yaml-conda      0.15.80
setuptools             60.10.0
six                    1.16.0
tqdm                   4.63.0
urllib3                1.26.9
wheel                  0.37.1

---MAC TERMINAL---

pip list
Package         Version

---

emoji           2.0.0
et-xmlfile      1.1.0
numpy           1.23.2
openpyxl        3.0.10
pandas          1.4.3
pip             22.2.2
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2022.2.1
setuptools      58.1.0
six             1.16.0

As you can see VSC has a lot more modules, but i dont understand why? I also tried to download my module in the visual studio code terminal, and that worked. but i thought that all the modules in python came from the same place? But judging by this, it certainly doesnt seem that way. Can someone please help me out with this, i want to be able to download modules in the mac terminal and then use them in visual studio code and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure which python installation is being used for pip. It is entirely possible that the mac terminal is using a different python installation than the vscode terminal.
In the bottom right corner of your vscode you should see [the selected interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVH8P.png)

Additionally i would advice you to always use a virtual python environment in oder to avoid these issues ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html))